What is the name of this MTV reality dating show?
Does anyone remember this TV show that aired on MTV? It was a dating show, and the concept was that a girl or boy couldn’t decide between two people which one to date, so they would both move in with that girl or boy's family for a week or something. In the end. that boy or girl would decide which one they would date. 

Welcome to M&TV. Please add anything that can help identify this TV show. Like when did you watch it or which country it belongs to or language of TV show or how characters looked like or any other plot details you remember. If you have added any of these details, very good. However, if you recall something, be it as the smallest detail, feel free to edit your question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title. Also see How to Ask Identify-this-X questions. Thank you.

The closest match seems to be "Parental Control".
Looking over "A Complete History of MTV's Dating Game Shows", none overly sound like the TV show you are remembering; however, I think the closest is Parental Control, which aired from 2005-2006 until 2010.
The initial premise was of a basic dating show, with the date trying to get to know the contestants better, and the parents picking the winning contestants. Eventually, the premise changed to one where the parents were not happy with their child's current significant other, and would pick additional contestants from which their child would ultimately choose from, at the end.
There does not appear to be any form of "live in", nor the initial premise of the date already trying to choose between multiple partners - all partners are "new" as of the start of the episode; however, of the MTV dating shows, this seems to mostly resemble the show you seem to be recalling.



Runner Ups
I found two additional shows that match minor aspects of your criteria, so it is possible that you may be mixing up multiple shows. There are two additional MTV dating shows that appear to bear minor similarity, not including the obvious.
Room Raiders - This appears to be the only MTV dating show with a focus on how contestants actually live. The contestants still were not living with the date, rather, the date would get to have a good look around each contestants house. This included having a good look around the bedroom, and the use of a black light.



Date My Mum - This appears to be the only other MTV dating show to include parents. The title explains it all; instead of dating the actual date, contestants would date the mother of their prospective dates.



